# Reading from appsettings.json file gives NullReferance Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to read some settings from my `appsettings.json` file but am getting a `NullReferenceException`. Using different SO posts as well as a few blogs I found on google I built the code and it all seems right, no compile errors and intillisense all works so I am not sure what I missed or did wrong.

Startup.CS:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddCaching();
        services.Configure<ApplicationSettingsModel>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
        services.AddScoped<IApplicationSettings, ApplicationSettings>();

        services.AddSession(o =>
        {
            o.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/ServerError");
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/PageNotFound");
        app.UseMvc();
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

IApplicationSettings:

```
public interface IApplicationSettings
{
    IOptions<ApplicationSettingsModel> AppSettings { get; }
}
```

ApplicationsSettings.cs:

```
public class ApplicationSettings : IApplicationSettings
{
    protected readonly IOptions<ApplicationSettingsModel> _AppSettings;

    public ApplicationSettings(IOptions<ApplicationSettingsModel> AppSettings)
    {
        _AppSettings = AppSettings;
    }

    public IOptions<ApplicationSettingsModel> AppSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return _AppSettings;
        }
    }

    public string GetAppVersion()
    {
        return _AppSettings.Value.AppVersion;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class ApplicationSettingsModel
{
    public string AppVersion { get; set; }
    public string BugZillaAPIKey { get; set; }
    public string EmailUser { get; set; }
    public string EmailPass { get; set; }
}
```

Class making the call:

```
public class EHAL
{
    private static IApplicationSettings _config;

    public EHAL(IApplicationSettings config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public static string Test()
    {
        return _config.AppSettings.Value.AppVersion;
    }
}
```

It is when I try to run `return _AppSettings.Value.AppVersion;` that the error is appearing. From the SO posts and blogs I think I am doing everything right but obviously I am screwing something up, just not sure what.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: can you change _AppSettings field to protected readonly instead of protected static?  What happens?

Comment: @mcbowes That generates a `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or proterty` error for `return _AppSettings.Value.AppVersion;`. If I remove the `static` keyword from that method then I get the same error on the `ViewData["Test"] = test.GetAppVersion();`

Comment: are you creating an instance of your test class?  var a = new test() ?

Comment: @mcbowes I don't think so. All code is in the post, where/how would I best do that? The goal is to be able to call into the test class' methods and just get the data needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what exactly you are trying to do, but you should be able to let the DI container handle the constructor injection, I made a small test app to inject the `test` class into a controller for example....

Change your test class to

```
public class test : Itest
{
    protected readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _AppSettings;

    public test(IOptions<AppSettings> AppSettings)
    {
        _AppSettings = AppSettings;
    }

    public IOptions<AppSettings> AppSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return _AppSettings;
        }
    }

    public string GetAppVersion()
    {
        return _AppSettings.Value.AppVersion;
    }
}
```

Add an interface `Itest`

```
public interface Itest
{
    IOptions<AppSettings> AppSettings { get; }
}
```

Add this a new line in your Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
services.AddScoped<Itest, test>();
```

Now in your controller you can do the following:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Itest _config;
        public HomeController(Itest config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var a = _config.AppSettings.Value.AppVersion;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

which will just inject an instance of your test class into the controller so you can use it during processing of the request.

Again, not 100% sure where you are going with this, this is an example of how you can get this to work.  Hope that helps!

EDIT:  You have some other options as well, you could just inject `IOptions<AppSettings>` into the controller constructor and just create an instance of the test class passing in the injected `IOptions<AppSettings>` as well.  That way you could get rid of the Itest interface and the extra config code in Startup.cs, just another thought.

EDIT:
So, I really think you should take a look at dependency injection, it really is the way to go.  But if you really don't want to go the DI root, you can do something like this, (change your static class to look like this):

```
public class test
{
    static IConfigurationSection _Settings;

    static test()
    {

        IConfiguration _config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        _Settings = _config.GetSection("AppSettings");
    }

    public static string GetAppVersion()
    {
        return _Settings["AppVersion"];
    }
}
```

Then you can make a call like so:

```
var a = test.GetAppVersion();
```

Although I'm not a big fan of doing this with statics I tried to keep in the spirit of what you were trying to do.  Really, DI is the way to go moving forward, strongly suggesting that you go that direction in future.

Comment: I am trying to create a class that contains methods to return certain values from the appsettings.json file. Controllers are not involved in this yet, there is the possibility that this data will be called directly by an action later in the application but at this point no controller needs direct access, just other classes. I have found many examples of this working by calling it from a controller so this is not actually helpful, sorry.

Comment: same thing can apply, in the constructor for the class, specify a `Itest` parameter, and let the DI container instantiate it and pass it in or just pass in `IOptions<AppSettings>`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "itest parameter". I don't know anything about DI. Also the constructor of the `test` class does take `IOptions<AppSettings>` but the constructor is not being called.

Comment: OK, I don't see a spot in your code where you are attempting to instantiate `test`, where are you doing that?

Comment: If you talking about something like `var test = new Test();` no where as I have to pass something in but have no idea what to pass in or where I really should be making this call (maybe in Startup.cs?)

Comment: Where are you expecting the constructor to be getting called if you aren't creating an object anywhere?  This line `services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));` is setting up the DI container

Comment: I have no idea. This is all new to me. I simply want to create a class that has methods I can call from anywhere in the app, be it controllers or other classes, so I can get certain values from the appsettings.json file. I can't find any information on how to do this unless it is in a controller and I am failing at adapting that code to work. If I have to call some constructor some where I don't know where the right place to do it or the right way of doing it. Or if there is even more stuff I need to be doing. Reading from web.config was simple in .net 4, this should be just as simple

Comment: I edited my answer to address you desire to keep this out of the DI framework.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Just as an aside, you can make use of the built in DI to inject parameters into all class constructors, not just controllers.  Might be useful for you in the future.

Comment: I don't necessary want to keep it out of DI I just don't know DI so if a more elegant, efficient, better solution can be made using DI I would love to know it.

Comment: Well, the DI way and non-DI way are in my answer, so pick which ever one you like.  Good luck on your project.

Comment: I tried to convert your DI code to work in a class and not a controller but I am running into the same null reference problem. Doing a debug shows that the constructor is still not firing. Is doing it via DI impossible unless I a do it in a controller?  I have updated my post to have the final code I built from you so you can see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: For your Web App, when a Request is handled and a Controller is instantiated you need to inject something, some sort of class as a parameter into the constructor.  This can either be your `Itest` interface or an interface to another class that will take an `Itest` interface in its constructor.  Make sure to register the classes using `AddScoped` as shown above.  So something like `Controller(IService)` -> `ConcreteService(Itest)`

Comment: So I am required to use controllers for DI then and there is no way to decouple this from a controller? If that is true then it seems like DI is much more work then it is worth. At this point I am just trying to read the values in an Error Logging class. If I have to inject and load those values at every action call and pass them down the pipe though call after call that seems really inefficient vs just making a single class not using DI and calling right into it from exactly where I need to use the values at.

Comment: No,  if you want to use your error logging class just add that to the constructor of whatever controller you'll want to have that error logging class available, that's it.  Now when the DI container creates your error logging class it will inject your other object into the constructor of your error logging class.  So no need to also add your settings reader class in the controller only the error logging class will need to be in the controller.

Comment: I tried to wire up the error handler in the controller but now I get a `Unable to resolve service for type` for it so at this point I am pretty sure there is something key missing between what your trying to tell me and what I am doing and I can't figure out what that is. I appreciate you trying to help but at this point either using DI or not I still have no way of reading the settings.